# Python: searching maximum data

Tags: python, list, max

There are two lists. one is code_list, the other is points

```
code_list= ['ab','ca','gc','ab','we','ca']
points = [30, 20, 40, 20, 10, -10]
```

These two lists connect each other like this: 'ab' = 30, 'ca'=20 , 'gc' = 40, 'ab'=20, 'we'=10, 'ca'=-10

From these two lists, If there are same elements, I wan to get sum of each element. Finally, I'll get a element which has the biggest point.
I'll hope to get a simple result like below:

```
'ab' has the biggest point: 50
```

Could you give me a your help?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use a [`collections.Counter()`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.Counter) instance:

```
>>> from collections import Counter
>>> code_list= ['ab','ca','gc','ab','we','ca']
>>> points = [30, 20, 40, 20, 10, -10]
>>> c = Counter()
>>> for key, val in zip(code_list, points):
...     c[key] += val
... 
>>> c.most_common(1)
[('ab', 50)]
```

`zip()` pairs up your two input lists.

It's that last call that makes the `Counter()` useful here, the `.most_common()` call uses `max()` internally for just one item, but for an argument greater than 1 `heapq.nlargest()` is used, and with no argument or asking for `len(c)`, `sorted()` is used.

Comment: I have a question. code_point = dict.fromkeys(code_list, points) <=== is this impossible way?

Comment: @PrimingRyan: First of all, you have duplicate keys in `code_list`, you'd loose some. Secondly, `.fromkeys()` takes the second argument and makes that the new value for *all* keys. So you'd have `{'ab': [30, 20, 40, 20, 10, -10], 'ca': [30, 20, 40, 20, 10, -10], 'gc': [30, 20, 40, 20, 10, -10]}` where the `[30, 20, 40, 20, 10, -10]` list values are *all the same list*. So, no, that would not work.

Comment: I have one more question. If points is not list, what am I gonna do? For example, I get a point data from these code: point = 0.0 for key in values: point += values[key]

Comment: That depends entirely what `points` is then, and that is too broad an option to discuss in comments. :-)

Comment: For example, I get a point data from these code: point = 0.0 for key in values: point += values[key]

Comment: @PrimingRyan: Then you just use `point = sum(values.itervalues)`, much more efficient. It's not clear what you are getting at though. Perhaps you could join the [Python chat room](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/6/python) to discuss what you can do.

Comment: I can't talk cause lack of point. Anyway, Thank for helping. I'll try to solve problem.

Comment: @PrimingRyan: Sorry about that; 20 points isn't that much, be patient and you'll soon be able to join us.

Answer (score 1):

There's another way, using [`collections.defaultdict`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.defaultdict):

```
>>> di = collections.defaultdict(int)
>>> for k,v in zip(code_list, points):
    di[k] += v

>>> max(di, key=lambda x:di[x])
'ab'
```

If you don't want to use `defaultdict` for some reason, just do this:

```
>>> di = {}
>>> for k,v in zip(code_list, points):
    if k not in di:
        di[k] = 0
    # or as suggested by Martijn Pieters
    # di[k] = di.get(k, 0) + v
    di[k] += v
```

Comment: You can also use `di[k] = di.get(k, 0) + v` to save yourself an `if` statement.

Answer (score 1):

Yet another way:

```
ans={}
for k,v in zip(code_list,points):
    ans.setdefault(k,[]).append(v)

print max(ans, key=lambda k:sum(ans[k]))
```

This creates a mapping of the keys in `code_points` with a list of the associated values like this:

```
{'ca': [20, -10], 'ab': [30, 20], 'gc': [40], 'we': [10]}
```

The line `max(ans, key=lambda k:sum(ans[k]))` takes that mapping and sums the lists together to get the max value.

Here is another way:

```
ans={k:0 for k in set(code_list)}
for k,v in zip(code_list,points):
    ans[k]+=v

print max(ans, key=lambda k: ans[k])
```

The line `ans={k:0 for k in set(code_list)}` creates a dictionary with every unique key from `code_list` with a value of 0. The loop then just adds them all up.

Or, as stated in the comments, this is probably better:

```
ans=dict.fromkeys(code_list,0)
for k,v in zip(code_list,points):
    ans[k]+=v

print max(ans, key=lambda k: ans[k])
```

Since there was some discussion on performance, here is a test:

```
from __future__ import print_function     # will run on Py 2.7 or 3.X
import timeit
from collections import Counter
from collections import defaultdict

points = [30, 20, 40, 20, 10, -10]
code_list= ['ab','ca','gc','ab','we','ca']

o1='''\
c=Counter()
for key, val in zip(code_list, points):
    c[key] += val

ans=c.most_common(1)    
'''

o2='''\
ans=defaultdict(int)

for k,v in zip(code_list,points):
    ans[k]+=v

m=max(ans, key=lambda k:ans[k])
'''

o3='''\
ans={}
for k,v in zip(code_list,points):
    ans.setdefault(k,[]).append(v)

m=max(ans, key=lambda k:sum(ans[k]))    

'''

o4='''\
ans={k:0 for k in set(code_list)}
for k,v in zip(code_list,points):
    ans[k]+=v

m=max(ans, key=lambda k: ans[k])  
'''

o5='''\
ans=dict.fromkeys(code_list,0)
for k,v in zip(code_list,points):
    ans[k]+=v

m=max(ans, key=lambda k: ans[k])  
'''

o6='''\
ans={}
for k,v in zip(code_list,points):
    ans[k]=ans.get(k,0)+v

m=max(ans, key=lambda k: ans[k])  
'''

fmt='{:20}{:>8.4f} seconds'
print (fmt.format('Counter:',timeit.timeit(o1, setup='from __main__ import points, Counter, code_list')))
print (fmt.format('defaultdict:',timeit.timeit(o2, setup='from __main__ import points, defaultdict, code_list')))
print (fmt.format('setdefault:',timeit.timeit(o3,setup='from __main__ import points, code_list')))
print (fmt.format('dict comprehension:',timeit.timeit(o4,setup='from __main__ import points, code_list')))
print (fmt.format('fromkeys:',timeit.timeit(o5,setup='from __main__ import points, code_list')))
print (fmt.format('dict.get():',timeit.timeit(o6,setup='from __main__ import points, code_list')))
```

Prints (on my machine with Python 3.3):

```
Counter:             13.0980 seconds
defaultdict:          4.8093 seconds
setdefault:           5.3016 seconds
dict comprehension:   3.8282 seconds
fromkeys:             3.3764 seconds
dict.get():           3.4785 seconds
```

Which shows that `Counter()` is pretty slow. The fastest is 3X faster

Comment: The latter method makes nearly two extra loops over the `code_list` entries, making it the most inefficient of all the options. Once to create the set, then again to create the `ans` dictionary default values. You could also use `ans = dict.fromkeys(code_list, 0)` to save one of those loops at least.

Comment: @MartijnPieters: True enough, but `dict.get()` is notoriously slow. I think that the `dict.fromkeys()` is a great comment tho!

Comment: @drewk: It is all relative. Using a full extra loop can easily be slower than adding the constant cost of `.get()`. And then there are `collections.defaultdict()` and `collections.Counter()` to avoid performance pitfalls too.

Comment: I have one question. If points is not list, what am I gonna do? For example, I get a point data from these code: point = 0.0 for key in values: point += values[key]

Comment: You can create a list or an iterator.

Comment: point = 0.0 for key in values: point += values[key] <=== from this code, is it possible to create list?

Comment: @PrimingRyan: It appears that if `values` is a dict which I will rename `Va`, you are using a loop to add all the values of Va together into `point`. You can get an unordered list of those values of Va by `point=Va.values()`

Comment: @MartijnPieters: Please see relevant timings. In this case, Counter *is* a performance pitfall!

Comment: @drewk: Very interesting. I'd love to explore where the performance difference comes from in that case; `Counter()` has a few other advantages that may offset this cost (multi-set use cases, using `.most_common()` with an argument other than 1), etc. Creating the class may be costly, or it may be the summing loop, etc. Comparing just some of these aspects with the other solutions could be insightful.

Comment: @drewk: and on 2.7, the `dict.get()` approach wins, as it does in your table of timings, not `.fromkeys()`.

Comment: @drewk: note that `Counter()` just uses the [`.__missing__()` hook](http://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#dict) provided by `dict` for subtypes; the biggest difference between `Counter()` and `defaultdict()` in that respect is that the latter uses C to provide the `__missing__` method.

Comment: @MartijnPieters: As usual -- you are right. :-)) `dict.get()` was fastest in that table. I have seen Counter() being kinda v1.0 slow at times, but it is definitely convenient. I cleaned up the timing code a bit just in case anyone is interested.

Comment: @drewk: a large part of the difference can be explained in that instantiating the `Counter` custom class is more expensive than the C types `dict` and `defaultdict`. You really need to remove the setup (creating the original lists and the original object) out of the time tests, but that makes comparing the `.fromkeys()` option harder of course.

Comment: @drewk: further testing shows that it is, unfortunately, largely down to the `.most_common()` method. Even with a `defaultdict` and `Counter` subclass using the faster C-based `__missing__` hook has `Counter` running behind `defaultdict` and `max()`. This is because the `heapq` module first tests if there are *any* elements in the input iterable (using `itertools` tricks), then having to use `chain()` to make `max()` work correctly again. This adds a lot of overhead for the `.most_common(1)` case vs. `max()` directly.